# Does Electrum reveal a wallets public key to Electrum Servers?

Tags: electrum, public-key, full-node, bip32-hd-wallets

When Electrum Bitcoin wallet queries a random Electrum Server does it send the public key to the server or does it send a batch of addresses to check?

For instance, after [setting up Electrum Personal Server](https://github.com/DriftwoodPalace/guides/blob/master/hodl-guide/hodl-guide_63_eps-win.md) between Electrum and a Bitcoin Core full node would it be prudent to create a new wallet and transfer funds to protect future privacy? (e.g. move funds from 84-0-0-0 to 84-0-0-1) Is it possible that previously connected to Electrum Servers that are potentially malicious have saved public keys to aid in chain analysis, or are they only given a batch of addresses to check making this attack impossible as you migrate to addresses further down the list?